# What’s wrong with my cactus?

Tags: plant-care, cactus

My cactus has been like this with cracked skin for months, I then noticed it had aphids and removed them with soap and water for one week and they went away, and just today I noticed these brown spots and black at the top of it! Does anyone know what this is and how do I treat it? I have potted today with new soil to see if that does anything. Any help will be greatly appreciated.[image]

Comment: Does it get direct sunlight? How many hours a day? One problem I see is etiolation, which is caused by lack of sunlight. But I think there are more problems here...

Comment: It’s by a window all day and night, it doesn’t get too much sun, I’ll try moving it to get more sun! Thx for the advice

Comment: Some plants do not tolerate insecticidal soap, if you used that?

Comment: It was doing it before I sprayed it with soap